# How did I get 2 points in Titanfall 2 multiplayer?

Tags: titanfall-2

So I just finished a game in Titanfall 2 (Xbox one) where I ended the game with 72 points. I had;

- 10 pilot kills
- 20 minion kills (no titans).

How could I have ended up with 72 points?

I'm under the impression that pilot kills are 5 points and minions (spectra and grunt) are 1 point so it would work out to be `(10 x 5) + (20 x 1) = 50 + 20 = 70`

Is there a rule regarding assists or something that I've been missing this whole time?

Comment: `(10 x 5) + (21 x 1) = 50 + 21 = 71`

Comment: @Memor-X Obviously a typo....I fixed it

Comment: you still have a typo, you're off by 1 point not 2

Comment: Tonight is not my night for writing this on my cell-phone....fixed it...again.. haha

Comment: Arent Spectra 2 and grunts 1?

Comment: @James in Titanfall 1 I believe so. Titanfall 2 scoring changed a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it isn't quite as cut and dry as your math suggests.

First, any activity done in the Epilogue will not count towards your point total, but will show up in the totals for Pilot, Titan, or Minion kills.

Secondly, if you killed a Reaper that will yield +5.

So, a plausible scenario could be

*Game*:

```
Pilots   Titans    Minions (+1)   (+5)
  9        0                17      2
```

*Epilogue*:

```
Pilots   Titans    Minions (+1)   (+5)
  1        0                 1
```

Which would yield a total of 10 pilot kills, 0 titan kills, 20 minion kills, and a game total of (9*5)+(17*1)+(2*5) = 45+17+10 = 72.

I am not saying this is exactly what happened, but this would be one possible way for how you would see that type of breakdown.

Comment: That makes perfect sense now that you mentioned it. I didn't take into account the Reapers adding +5 and not being on that scoreboard.

Comment: Yeah, it can be a little tricky to determine the specifics from the breakdown. I wish there was a K/D ratio on the attrition scoreboard (or at least deaths) :( Oh well, still boat loads of fun in my opinion!